# how to return ajax response in function

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I am having a requirement where i need to validate jar file and the contents of Jar file.

the `validation of contents of Jar` file is done in my servlet and in-response i am getting the string from servlet.

Based on the response generated from the servlet i am validating it in a function.

My Code looks like this

```
function validateSteps(step) {
    var appctxpath = document.getElementById("appcontextpath").getAttribute("value");
    var isStepValid = true;
    var buttonPress = document.getElementById("buttonClick").value;
    // validate step 1
    if (step == 1) {
    var result = true;
    if(buttonPress != "P")
    {

    var valid = $("#formID").validationEngine('validate');
        //var vars = $("#formID").serialize();
        //alert(valid);
        if (valid == true) {
            //alert("Hi");
            result = true;
        } else {
            result = false;

            $("#formID").validationEngine();
        //return false;

        }
if(result == true)
{
var result;
    var connectorJarFile = document.getElementById("conncetorJar").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("conncetorJar", connectorJarFile);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST",appctxpath+"/ajax/AdminIlantusAppAddStepOne", true);
    xhr.send(formdata);

    xhr.onload = function(e) 
    {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) 
    {
        var msg=xhr.responseText;

                 if(msg == "Invalid Jar File"){
                alert("!Invalid jar file");
                document.getElementById('errfn').innerHTML="This is Invalid jar file";
                return false;
             }
            else{
                alert("valid jar");
                document.getElementById('errfn').innerHTML="";
                return true;
            }       

        }
    };
}
```

If the message is `Invalid Jar File` I should stop the control going to the next page.
for that i kept `return false;` in `if condition`.

Still the control is going to the next page. what should i do to solve this problem??

Comment: Have you checked if the correct message is really returned? Does the alert pop up?

Comment: Because ajax is asynchronous by default, it is not waiting any response to go or not to the next page. Then you should implement this logic inside the ajax callback function. But wait, i don't see any logic there to go or not to a next page. You should post this relevant part too

Comment: @kaktus  Thanks for the reply, Yes It is showing the alert message

Comment: @roasted Edited, Plz check it

Comment: You have two functions 'validateSteps' ???

Comment: oops sorry..was in hurry.....only 1 function is there.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax is asyncrounous which means that your `validateSteps()` call will complete long before the ajax success handler (that tries to return false). That is why the `return false` has no effect in the ajax success handler.

A solution would be to submit the form if the AJAX says everything is valid, and if not - don't submit the form:

```
        if(msg == "Invalid Jar File"){
            alert("!Invalid jar file");
            document.getElementById('errfn').innerHTML="This is Invalid jar file";
        }
        else{
            alert("valid jar");
            document.getElementById('errfn').innerHTML="";
            $('#formID').submit(); // submit form
        }
```

Or change the submission to a redirect if that's what you want.

Comment: Tried this..but i got the same result

Comment: Where are you redirecting to the next page? You need to remove that.